# Curl and jq replace substring in value

Tags: json, string, command-line, edit, jq

With curl I'm getting json from github api:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/pulls?label=comp%3A+zones&state=closed&page=1&per_page=5
```

result:

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/pulls/33703",
    "id": 338899730,
    "node_id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0MzM4ODk5NzMw",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/33703",
    "diff_url": "https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/33703.diff",
    "patch_url": "https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/33703.patch",
    "issue_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/issues/33703",
    "number": 33703,
    "state": "closed",
    "locked": false,
    "title": "add AOT mode default to version 9 upgrade doc",

      [...]
```

with jq :

```
$ curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/pulls?label=comp%3A+zones&state=closed&page=1&per_page=2' | jq --raw-output '.[] | "\(.id) \(.title)"'
```

I can nicely format it as

```
338899730 add AOT mode default to version 9 upgrade doc
338868666 update jiali's info on collaborator page of angular.io
```

How can remove `add` and `update` from the title value before output?

Comment: The file residing at the link you posted uses a different format for titles, like `docs: blah blah`

Comment: true but it's generally about replacing in values

Comment: Hi @Dmitry this is also a nice way. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sub`, e.g.:

```
.[]
| "\(.id) \(.title|sub("^(add|update) *";""))"
```